# How to clear localStorage on browser crash?

Tags: javascript

I have an application with a live chat feature. When it opens, the chat is in a new popup window. While this window is open, I need to prevent the user from opening another chat window (they can only have one chat going at a time). So, I have a simple flag, the following code fires when the popup loads:

```
localStorage.setItem('chatOpen', true);
window.onunload = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('chatOpen', false);
};
```

And I check this flag before opening the popup. It works fine normally, but if the browser crashes, the window.onunload event does not fire, and then the user can never open the chat popup ever again. How can I remedy this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing localStorage on page load? Every time preventively?

Comment: Does it have to be local storage? How about a session cookie?

Comment: Clearing on page load would be problematic if the user has the popup open, we don't want to clear it.

Comment: If you can predict where the browser might crash a try... finally might help?

Comment: Session cookie - since they are separate windows, my understanding is that they have different sessions. This is why sessionStorage would not work for me; each window had its own instance of it.

Comment: use a storage event to talk back and forth. make a cancel chat method to fire when one is already opened. when the chat opens, save a value to localstorage, to trigger the event in all other tabs. if a tab is already chatting, save another value to cancel the chat in the new tab. tab ids work, but e.target should work also. it's async, but it should "bounce back" in under 20ms, so you can wait without user harm. you can also use SharedWorkers for "js ipc"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you change a logic a bit: start a timer, which update timestamp every second... and on the other side, if `current time - timestamp > 1` sec, means that last page has been closed

pseudocode:

```
on load : 
 if localStorage has value with key chattimestamp and datetime.now -localstorage[chattimestamp] < 1 sec
      another instance is oppened
 else
    settimer that every 1 sec update timestamp to localstorage[chattimestamp]
```

I think you can choose more than 1 second, actually 5-10 sec should be ok

Comment: I like this! I was thinking more around 5 seconds as well. This could definitely work, I'll test and report back, thanks!